# How to configure ToscaWidgets 2 on a TurboGears 2.2 with mount Proxy deploy

Tags: python-2.7, reverse-proxy, turbogears, turbogears2, toscawidgets

I have a working turbo gears 2.2 website, deployed as a mount reverse-proxy, exp:

https://Some-Domain.com/**mySite**

I know how to configure the webserver to work as a mounted site, but I don't know how to do that for ToscaWidgets. Tw2 is looking for its css file in the wrong path. I can see that with Firebug.

Does anybody know how should I configure my ToscaWidgets to the right path?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tw2 has a `script_name` option. You can set that through `custom_tw2_config.script_name` in tg2.
That should guarantee that TW2 correctly generates urls for resources in case of a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, can you give more specific instructions?

Comment: Ok, what I did was insert in ../config/ **middleware.py** : `twc.middleware.Config.script_name = my_prefix`

Comment: Sorry, I though instructions were good enough, the exact process is adding to config/app_cfg.py base_config.custom_tw2_config.script_name property You can use base_config.custom_tw2_config.script_name to override any default configuration option set by TG. Doing it in other places will get TG override your options if he has a default for it.